# automake according to Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, automake

Following description can be found in Ubuntu Software Center (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) for Automake package:

> Automake 1.15 fails to work in a number of situations that Automake
>   1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, 1.11 and 1.14 did, so previous versions are available as separate packages.

Few questions arise from this:

- Why are versions 1.12 and 1.13 not mentioned in the list?
- Fact that 1.15 fails to work in a number of situation - is this a problem of Automake or integration-in-Ubuntu's one?
- Description mentions previous versions are available as separate packages - where is that availability, GNU or other automake distribution servers or Ubuntu packages distribution system?

Answer (score 1):

All of those packages should be available in Ubuntu, for example as `automake-1.14`.

As for the *fails to work in a number of situations* comment, I would expect it's likely because Automake 1.15 changed something which broke compatibility, which has been common in the past.

As to why certain versions aren't listed there, that'd be a question that only the specific person who packaged automake (probably a Debian developer) could answer. Changes to packages in Ubuntu usually don't alter the package description, and you can see [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/automake) has the same description.

Comment: "Changes to packages in Ubuntu usually don't alter the package description" do you like to say with this "1.13 version got 1.12 version number" is one of all possible reasons?

Comment: "All of those packages should be available in Ubuntu, for example as automake-1.14" Me can only see, except for 1.15, the 1.11 one in Software Center. Ubuntu's new Software app does not offer any version, so wonderful this Ubuntu Software app is.

Comment: No, the versions are correct. I mean when Ubuntu makes changes to a package that's pulled from debian, the core features of the package are not generally changed. There are just additional patches for bug fixes, or integration, for example.

Comment: OK, then those are perhaps not in Debian either, and there is a bug upstream in the package description.  That is simply a bug though.